# Node.js Hapi cant show the caught value

Tags: node.js, hapi

So I'm creating a handler.js file that can caught values from my front-end.

```
const connectToDatabase = (request, h) => {
  const { username, password, host, port } = request.payload;

  // Perform any desired operations with the received values
  // ...

  // Build the response message with the provided values
  const message = `Received values: username=${username}, password=${password}, host=${host}, port=${port}`;

  return { success: true, message };
};

module.exports = {
  connectToDatabase
};
```

the routes will be on https:localhost:3000/api/connect-to-database

I tried to check it with postman with this raw json :
{
"username": "root",
"password": "",
"host": "localhost",
"port": "3306"
}

It works fine but I can see the value that I inputted :
{
"success": true,
"message": "Received values: username=undefined, password=undefined, host=undefined, port=undefined"
}

I'm pretty new to back-end so it would be good if someone can pinpoint the error

Comment: What's in `request.payload`? Get in the habit of debugging your code with `console.log`.

Comment: Ok I tried it and seems like the payload caught the inserted values but why can't I see it : 
Server running on http://localhost:3000
Payload: {
  "username": "root",
  "password": "",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": "3306"
}

Username: undefined
Password: undefined
Host: undefined
Port: undefined

sorry I'm pretty new to this

Comment: Payload is probably the raw string rather than a parsed JSON object. Either do `JSON.parse(request.payload)`, or try setting your your content type header in postman to json

Comment: Ok my bad seems like I didn't changed the json header on postman. Ok now it's working. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Please ask the author of the comment if he wants to write a regular answer; if not (probably not!) you can self-answer to your question, mentioning the correct input received. SO is a Q&A site!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the fix now, seems like I forgot to set the test data into .json file on the Postman. It was a text file before. Everything fixed now